# Find only distinct values from multiple columns in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let us assume a Postgres table like this

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  value_1 VARCHAR(255),
  value_2 VARCHAR(255),
  value_3 VARCHAR(255),
  value_4 VARCHAR(255),
  value_5 VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Each row has a different value for each of the columns, and each row has the same values, but in different columns.

```
INSERT INTO
  example
VALUES
  ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
  ('b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a'),
  ('c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b'),
  ('d', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c'),
  ('e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
```

Yielding

```
# SELECT * FROM example;
 value_1 | value_2 | value_3 | value_4 | value_5 
---------+---------+---------+---------+---------
 a       | b       | c       | d       | e
 b       | c       | d       | e       | a
 c       | d       | e       | a       | b
 d       | e       | a       | b       | c
 e       | a       | b       | c       | d
(5 rows)
```

How can I select all the unique values between several columns spanning over multiple rows so that I get only one column list with distinct values `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, `'d'`, `'e'`? It is not known if each value exists in each column and the order of the values.

Comment: This is poor table design...does your table even have a primary key column?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: You cannot know that, because you don't know what this table represents. Let's say what is modeled here is a lottery where five letters are drawn in a series, and in the database we are not interested in *when* a combination was drawn, but only *whether* it was drawn. For this case, the table could be an appropriate model.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't think your comment exactly helps to answer anything, it is a table called `example` for a reason and as it is just for the sake of brevity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading up on @Andrei Odegov's `unnest`, it looks like that function can return multiple rows.  To return the unique values from any row or column:

```
select  distinct unnest(array[value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4, value_5])
from    example
```

Comment: This looks so far like the most elegant answer, thank you! I tried earlier to do a test with `unnest`, but my array construction syntax was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have a table of related values, but in your query you don't care about these relations; you only want to know which values exist in the table.

One way to treat all the values the same is writing one query for each column and then union the results:

```
select value_1 as value from mytable
union
select value_2 as value from mytable
union
select value_3 as value from mytable
union
select value_4 as value from mytable
union
select value_5 as value from mytable
order by value;
```

Comment: Thank you for this! `SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT DISTINCT ... UNION SELECT DISTINCT)' chain was what I came up as well, but I was wondering if there were solutions that felt more elegant that I haven't thought about

Comment: I updated the original question by defining that I want to get only distinct values, so if you want to update your answer please do so. :)

Comment: `UNION [DISTINCT]` already gets you distinct values. (What you have in mind is `UNION ALL`.)

Answer (score 1):

Check the solution that uses [`unnest`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) array function. But what about the leading/trailing spaces or data like these `'ab', '', 'c', 'd', 'e'`?:

```
select version();
-- drop table if exists example;

CREATE TABLE example (
  value_1 VARCHAR(255),
  value_2 VARCHAR(255),
  value_3 VARCHAR(255),
  value_4 VARCHAR(255),
  value_5 VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO example
VALUES
  ('a ', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
  ('b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a'),
  (' c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b'),
  ('d', ' e ', 'a', 'b', 'c'),
  ('e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
  ('ab', '', 'c', 'd', 'e');

with
  t1 as (
    select
      row_number() over(order by 0) as id,
      unnest(array[value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4, value_5]) as val
    from example
  )
select distinct
  string_agg(val, '' ORDER BY val) as val
from t1
group by id
;
```

Results:

```
   val   
---------
 ab cde
 a bcde
 abcde
 abcd e
```

Try it on [</>OneCompiler](https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3zwrvujn4).

Comment: Interesting answer!  The `id` is a row number in the original table. Then the query orders the values within their original row with `string_agg(val, '', order by val)` and returns the unique ordered rows.

Comment: This answer does not answer what was asked: to get rows with each unique value (i.e. `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, `'d` and `'e'`). Why do you aggregate the strings?

Comment: @adrenalin, you are right. I voted for your answer.